# Pics-label meta tag in html 5

Tags: html, metadata, meta-tags, w3c-validation

I'm rebuilding an existing site in html5.
There is a `Pics-label`   meta element in the header.

```
<meta http-equiv="Pics-label" content="(somecontent)" >
```

When I validate it through http://validator.w3.org/ it gives the following error.

```
Bad value Pics-label for attribute http-equiv on element meta.
```

I searched the internet but couldn't find anything helpful.
Please help me on this.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://www.w3.org/PICS/labels.html

Comment: yes. I went through this. There is nothing mentioned here regarding html5. Also note that the page validation passed when it is validated for html4.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ignore the error message. This a bug in the validator: it has not been updated to recognize the values specified in the [registry](http://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/PragmaExtensions). In response to the [bug report](http://bugzilla.validator.nu/show_bug.cgi?id=966) on March 1, 2013, this bug was acknowledged, but it has not been fixed yet.

The background is that unlike previous versions of HTML, HTML5 restricts the use of `<meta http-equiv=...>` elements to a specific, though mutable, set of header names.

Comment: Thank you very much. I know it's too much to ask. But could you please suggest any work around or any way to fix this?

Comment: @UdayanthaUdyWarnasuriya, there is nothing to be fixed in your document in this respect. An incorrect error message from a checking tool should just be ignored.